# For primes $p,q$, what are the solutions to $x^2=(p+q)x\pmod{pq}$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

For primes $p,q$, what are the solutions to $$x^2=(p+q)x\pmod{pq}$$

Comment: Please edit in your attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: Can't really find a way to solve this..

Comment: If you don't know CRT: note that it's equivalent to $\,(x-p)(x-q)\equiv 0 \pmod {pq},\,$ i.e. $\,pq\mid(x-p)(x-q),\,$ and $\,pq\mid mn\iff p\mid m, q\mid n\, $ or $\,p\mid n,q\mid n,\,$ or $\,pq\mid n\,$ or $\,pq\mid n,\,$ by unique factorization.

Comment: And how can use it?

Comment: Same as in the linked dupes, except you have roots $\,p,q\,$ vs $\,-2,-3$ or $\,0,1\ \ $

Comment: You'll get the roots $\, p,\ q,\ 0,\ p+q\ \ \ $

Comment: Can you please upload the full answer, still can't understand what to do and how. :(

Comment: Do you not know CRT?  If you do the linked answers explain in detail how to use it to solve such quadratics.

Comment: As an optimization note that if $\,r\,$ is a root of $\,x(x-b)\,$ then so too is $\,b-r,\,$ so the roots come in pairs that sum to $\,b\,$ (as in Vieta's formula). Here $\,b = p+q\,$ and our root pairs are $\,p,q\,$ and $\,0,\,p+q.\,$ These are the solutions of all possible combinations of the roots listed in Bernard's answer, e.g. $p$ is the root $\,\equiv (p,p)\equiv (0,p)\pmod{p,q}\,$ and $\,q\,$ is that $\equiv (q,q)\equiv (q,0)\,$ and their sum $\,p+q\,$ that $\,\equiv (p+q,p+q)\equiv (q,p). \ \ $

Comment: The $\,4\,$ combinations of $\,x\equiv p,q\pmod {\!p},\,$ $\,x\equiv p,q\pmod {\!q}\,$ are $\qquad\qquad\begin{align} &(p,p), (p,q), (q,p), (q,q)\!\pmod{(p,q)}^{\phantom{|^|}}\\\[.3em]
\mapsto &\ \ \  p,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0,\ \  \ \ p\!+\!q,\ \ \ \ q\ \ \ \text{when solved by CRT}\end{align}\ \ $

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If anything still is not clear you can ask further questions in comments here or in the linked answers. It will be clarified when you learn CRT as a ring isomorphism $\,\Bbb Z/pq\cong \Bbb Z/p\times \Bbb Z/q\,$ (which I do implicitly by doing arithmetic on the CRT solution tuples).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use  the *Chinese remainder theorem*: for $p\ne q$,
$$\mathbf Z/pq\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z$$
so the given congruence is equivalent to the system of congruences
$$\begin{cases}
x^2\equiv qx\mod p \\
x^2\equiv px\mod q
\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}
x\equiv 0 &\text{or }x\equiv q\mod p \\
x\equiv 0 &\text{or } x\equiv p \mod q
\end{cases}$$
Next, you can use the inverse isomorphism of the Chinese remainder theorem, which relies on a Bézout's relation $up+vq=1$:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z &\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/pq\mathbf Z \\
(x\bmod p,y\bmod q)&\longmapsto yup+xvq\bmod pq
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please explain more ?

Comment: Tried to solve this with the Chinese raminder theorem, couldnt finish.

Comment: Did you try with the explicit  inverse isomorphim?

Comment: havn't learned it yet

Comment: only untill CRT and also cant understand it much.

Comment: The general formula  given by the inverse isomorphism is that the solution of the linear system  of congruences: $\begin{cases}x\equiv\alpha\mod p,\\x\equiv\beta\mod q,\end{cases}\;$ is given by $\; x\equiv \beta up+\alpha vq\mod pq $, where $up+vq=1$ is a Bézout's relation between $p$ and $q$ (which need not be prime – only coprime).

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite the modular equivalence as $$x^2-(p+q)x+kpq=0$$for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

The discriminant of this quadratic is $(p+q)^2-4kpq$. To check whether there exists a square root of the discrimnant, we have to evaluate ${(p+q)^2-4kpq\choose pq}$, the legendre symbol. However, this is equal to ${(p+q)^2\choose pq}$ trivially, and this tells us that the discriminant is in fact a quadratic residue.

Hence, our solutions are of the form $$\frac{p+q\pm\sqrt{(p+q)^2-4kpq}}2$$for $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: How you got from the first equation to the second in a trivial way?

Comment: $4kpq\equiv0$ in $\bmod {pq}$.

Comment: Is this the equations department of the equation?

Comment: @אבגדיזיין This is not a good way to proceed. See the other approaches.

Comment: Why not? what else I can do?